# How to Execute cmd or fetch value from host inside container?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, microservices

Host : ubuntu
Installed Docker kubernetes on it
After logging into one container, can i run some command to fetch some data from host?
example : helm version from host

Comment: The whole point with containers is isolation. An app in a container should in almost all cases not know about the environment it is run in. A microservice should communicate with other services using the network, typically http.

Answer (score 0):

The whole point with containers is isolation. An app in a container should in almost all cases not know about the environment it is run in. A microservice should communicate with other services using the network, typically http